# :hover state is still active after going back in browser by using browser back-button

Tags: html, css

I hover over an link in my nav and it changed its color.

I have a strange problem in Firefox and Safari: when i go back in the browser(by clicking the back-button with the mouse) after hovering a link the color of the link does not change to its original state. It has the hover-state.

Only after the mouse reenters the site the color is changed back to black.
What can i do to change the color of the link back to black immediately on pageload. Why the hover-state seems to be active on pageload?

This happens when I hover a link an afterwords I go directly with the mouse to the back button of the browser.

Thanks a lot!

#### My css :

```
a {
    outline: none;  
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
    color: black;
} 

a:hover, a:active {
    color: rgb(120,140,150);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The solution

Just replace ...

```
a {
    outline: none;  
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
    color: black;
} 

a:hover, a:active {
    color: rgb(120,140,150);
}
```

... with ...

```
a {
    outline: none;  
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
} 

a:hover {
    color: rgb(120,140,150);
}
```

(See [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mLbrfdaL/2/) for a demo)

... and your links should work as expected.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is referring to...  he means that the ACTIVE state is appearing when he goes back, not the visited link state.  I've seen that too; that the browser doesn't redraw the page on back.

Comment: thanks for your help, but this does not change the :active state when i go back in the browser. Unfortunately.

Comment: @buckdanny : I just edited my answer. Can you try this code and see if this solves your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve it. what @andi is writing sounds right, but what to do to redraw the page on back?

Comment: @buckdanny : Could you show us a demo of what exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need an active state and the hover state will be sufficient, I think you might be able to remove `a:active` from your CSS to avoid the problem.  You can leave `a:hover` as is, since that's not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem. What solved it for me was to put the `:hover` state in a media query to make it only appear in the Desktop.

Like this:

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    a:hover {
        color: rgb(120,140,150);
    }
}
```